# Eslint rule to catch useless spaces in JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

E.g. `<img /> <img />` or `<span> text </span>`

Is there a rule that catches these spaces, which are ignored by React?

Comment: This is a `jsx` behavior: "JSX removes whitespace at the beginning and ending of a line. It also removes blank lines."  https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#string-literals-1 . I'm not aware of any lint rule which ensure this, since they will be removed anyway

Comment: I think the reason why this lint rule doesn't exist is because useless whitespaces will be removed anyway when the code is minified. Meanwhile you can use code formatters like `prettier` to achieve that: https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#html-whitespace-sensitivity